# How to open list form as editifs.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

How to open list form directly as editifs.aspx? By default, it opens displayifs.aspx but i need to open aditifs.aspx.

I even et the edit view by defaut in Infopath but when we open the form is only open as editifs.aspx

Im using InfoPath and Sharepoint 2010

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can customize your editifs.aspx in SharePoint by using the gear menu and select edit page, there you can add an script editor with some javascript to redirect the user to the Editifs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To open list item using editifs.aspx by default, you can do as the followings:

1. Open SharePoint Designer, find the list, open list AllItems.aspx
   page, advanced mode.
2. Change the view to split mode.
3. Put the mouse on one item Title field, to find the xsl easier, you can enter a backspace on the item Title. In the code view, the following code will be chosen: change the “$FORM_DISPLAY” to “$FORM_EDIT”.
4. After changing, the code is like：

   ```
                       <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="$XmlDefinition/List/@TemplateType != 301">
             <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$FORM_EDIT}&amp;ID={$ID}&amp;ContentTypeID={$thisNode/@ContentTypeId}" onclick="EditLink2(this,{$ViewCounter});return false;" target="_self">
                           <xsl:call-template name="LinkTitleValue.LinkTitle">
                               <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                               <xsl:with-param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="$ShowAccessibleIcon"/>
                           </xsl:call-template>
             </a></xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
               <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$FORM_EDIT}&amp;ID={$ID}" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">
                           <xsl:call-template name="LinkTitleValue.LinkTitle">
                               <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                               <xsl:with-param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="$ShowAccessibleIcon"/>
                           </xsl:call-template>
             </a>
         </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Created_x0020_Date.ifnew='1'">
                       <xsl:call-template name="NewGif.LinkTitle">
                           <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
   ```

Reference:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0e8abd00-1b22-4190-80f1-6c13b209555e/how-to-open-list-form-as-editifsaspx?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious